# (How) Can you curry compose monadic functions?

Tags: scala, haskell, monads, currying, function-composition

I have the following functions:

```
f: a -> m[b]
g: (b,c) -> m[d]
h: (a,c) -> m[d]
```

How can `h` be expressed as a composition of `f` and `g`?

Using `do/for` notation we can implement `h` easily like so:

```
h: (a,c) => {
 for {
  b <- f(a)
  d <- g(b,c)
 } yield (d)
}
```

However, I'm curious if we can express it like so: `h = f andThen g` where `andThen` is used like a *monadic composition* operator. For example:

```
f: a -> m[b]
g: b -> m[c]
h: a -> m[c] = f andThen g
```

I'm assuming that creating such an `andThen` function is possible in languages like Haskell (e.g., Kliesli `>=>`). In Scala we can write one like so: (example in Scala naming `andThenE` since `andThen` is already defined on instance of `Function1`).

```
implicit class AndThenEither[A,B](val e: Function1[A,Either[_,B]]) {
    def andThenE[C](f:Function1[B, Either[_,C]]): Function1[A, Either[_,C]] = {
      (v1: A) => e.apply(v1).flatMap(b => f.apply(b))
    }
}
```

Given this, it seems if we curry the functions we *may* be able to achieve such a composition (or at least it *looks* possible):

```
f: a -> m[b]
g: b -> c -> m[d]
h: a -> c -> m[d] = f andThen g
```

In *theory* this could work but I have no idea if this is possible or how to go about implementing something like this in Scala (or Haskell, although I'm more fluent with the former).

Let's say we had the following functions:

```
case class Error(e:String)
case class Output(i: Int, f: Float, s: String)
case class IntermediateOutput(i:Int, f:Float)

def f(i:Int): Either[Error, IntermediateOutput] = Right(IntermediateOutput(i+1, i*0.33)
def g(io: IntermediateOutput, s: String): Either[Error, Output] = Right(Output(io.i, io.f, "hello "+s)) 

val h: (Int, String) => Either[Error, Output] = f andThen g

val result = h(1, "world!") //Right(Output(2, 0.33, "hello world!")
```

Is this even possible/achievable? If not Scala, how could we go about *curry composing monadic functions* in Haskell or in general?

Is this a known thing or do we explicitly distinguish between currying being applicable to non-monadic functions and reserving the `andThen` like operator for monadic ones, but avoid mixing the two? If so, I can see a strong case for the `do/for` notation. However, I'm not entirely convinced that it's impossible and would like to understand this further. Perhaps the code would just be cluttered and that's okay - I'm simply curious. I stumbled on such a situation as a result of working on an existing problem and I couldn't cast it like so.

Comment: In Haskell you have the [Kleisi Arrow composition operator](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-) `(>=>)` defined in `Control.Monad` which is exactly your `andThen` function

Comment: I guess `h = flip (\c -> f >=> flip g c)` or something like that in Haskell. If you don't mind `f :: a -> m b; g :: c -> b -> m d; h :: c -> a -> m d` (note the pre-flipped arguments to `g` and `h`), then `h c = f >=> g c` is not too horrible. Still, I'm not sure either of those is more readable or more desirable than `h a c = do { b <- f a; g b c }`.

Comment: @Ismor - Yes. I’m aware of it. I should’ve been more explicit/clear about it. I’ll update the question.

Comment: Something that’s come up in passing but I think is worth bring explicit about: no, there’s no obstacle to currying here. In Haskell, `g` and `h` would be written curried unless you were doing something very specific. You can write your `andThen` just fine as `andThen_1_2 :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> c -> m d) -> (a -> c -> m d) ; andThen_1_2 f g = \a c -> do b <- f a ; g b c`, the generalized version of what Daniel Wagner wrote. That uses `do` notation, but uses it to _implement_ the desired function; it's true that existing approaches to do so pointfreely are kinda clunky, but that's ok.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Haskell there are some standard (i.e. in the `base` lib) operators for that.

First, your `andThen` function is the well known [*Kleisli composition*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-):

```
>=> :: (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> a -> m c

        a -> m b
               b -> m c
       -----------------
        a        -> m c
```

This operator doesn't match exactly with your types due to `g` operating in tuples and `f` not returning a a tuple. This can be easily overcome with `do/for` notation

```
h :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> ( (b,c) -> m d ) -> (a,c) -> m d
h f g (a, c) = do
  b <- f a
  g (b, c)
```

I'd go for the solution above, but for the sake of curiosity, this problem has been faced already and the Haskell's `base` library introduces a category-theory-oriented module called `Control.Arrow`. [Here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html) you can find a pletora of operators to achive your goal:

```
import Control.Arrow

hKleisli :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> ( (b,c) -> m d ) -> (a,c) -> m d
hKleisli f g = runKleisli $ 
  first (Kleisli f) >>> Kleisli g
--|                 |   |- this is just boilerplate
--|                 |- This composes Categories
--|- this converts f into a function operating in tuples

{--
       Kleisli f  :: Kleisli m  a     b         --  a    -> m  b
---------------------------------------------
first (Kleisli f) :: Kleisli m (a,c) (b,c)      -- (a,c) -> m (b,c)
        Kleisli g :: Kleisli m       (b,c) d    --            (b,c) -> m d
---------------------------------------------
first (Kleisli f)  
    >>> Kleisli g :: Kleisli m (a,c)       d    -- (a,c)            -> m d
--}
```

### EDIT

With regard to your comment: The original question is: how can we compose `f` and `g` after currying `g`? and my solution looks more like *let's uncurry `f` to work with `g`* so I agree it isn't a complete solution. Ok let's solve your question, but first, some notes:

- from the type `h :: a -> c -> m d` It should be clear that we want some monad that behaves like `m` but takes `c` into acount.
- from the type of `f :: a -> m b` we know that `f` has no access to `c` and somehow It should be brought into scope. Otherwise, `f` and `h` could never be the same monad.
- Tankfully we can add an extra argument to f using `const . f :: a -> c -> m b`

So far we have

```hs
{-- 
The name of the type variables are chosen to match the ones used in this post, but are different in ghci

        f :: a      -> m b
        g :: (b,c)  -> m d

const . f :: a -> c -> m b
  curry g :: b -> c -> m d
--}
```

Now It seems obvious that we need to use some monadic operator with `const . f` and `curry g` but the problem is that we need to preserve the monad `m` and that can't be achive unless we wrap the result into some new data type, otherwise, the monad we would be refering is the function monad `(->)` (Is this haskell specific? I think no). The obvious choice is to use the `Kleisli` monad (`ghc >= 8.10`). So now we have:

```hs
{-- 
The name of the type variables are chosen to match the ones used in this post, but are different in ghci

        f :: a      -> m b
        g :: (b,c)  -> m d

const . f :: a -> c -> m b
curry   g :: b -> c -> m d
                 |- This result lives in the -> monad

Kleisli . const . f :: a -> Kleisli m c b
Kleisli . curry   g :: b -> Kleisli m c b
--}

import Control.Monad
import Control.Arrow

f :: Monad m => a -> m b
f = undefined

g :: Monad m => (b, c) -> m d
g = undefined

-- And now, We have curryed and composed g
h :: Monad m => a -> c -> m b
h = runKleisli . (f' >=> g')
  where
    f' :: Monad m => a -> Kleisli m c b
    f' = Kleisli . const . f
    g' :: Monad m => b -> Kleisli m c d
    g' = Kleisli . curry g
```

Notice, that this can be done using different monads than `Kleisli`. Probably all solutions are isomorphic up to curry / uncurry. As long as you can bring `c` to the scope of `f` and find a monad that preserves the behaviour of `m` you can apply this.

Comment: @Ismor - This is an interesting way of sidestepping the problem by (conceptually) "wrapping" `f` into another function to get type alignment via `(a,c)->m(b,c)` so that the chain can continue. I understand it _solves_ the composition problem but doesn't answer my question regarding "currying + composition" and whether a solution exists under the assumption of "all curried single arg functions" that return a monad _at the end_. Any thoughts?

Comment: @PhD I've added an Edit section

Comment: @Ismor - This is a much appreciated effort on your part. I'm digesting what you've posted to understand how it all works out. I can only be indebted for the effort you've taken to help clarify this. For this you have my (and I'm sure the community's) many thanks!